# Is the wedge sum of two spaces $X$ and $Y$ homotopy equivalent to $X$ and $Y$ connected by a line?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

To state my question more formally, I am wondering if for any two pointed topological spaces $(X,x_0)$ and $(Y,y_0)$, their wedge sum $X\vee Y$ is homotopy equivalent to the space $Z=X\underset{x_0\thicksim0}{\sqcup}[0,1]\underset{y_0\thicksim 1}\sqcup Y$.

I can contract $[0,1]$ to the connecting point in $X\vee Y$ and get a homotopy equivalence candidate $Z\rightarrow X\vee Y$, but I can't produce a homotopic inverse $X\vee Y\rightarrow Z$. I was wondering if this really does hold for any spaces $X, Y$, as it seems really intuitively true to me, as well as what the aforementioned map should be in this case. If it doesn't hold in general, then are there conditions on $X$ and $Y$ that guarantee it does?

Comment: To see intuitively why it must fail in general wedge together two copies of the comb space.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your construction enjoys the nice property that if $X$ and $Y$ are simply connected, so is $Z$ (can you see why?). On the contrary, it is not true that if $X$ and $Y$ are simply connected, so is $X\vee Y$. The famous counterexample is the [Griffiths twin cone](https://wildtopology.com/2014/06/28/the-griffiths-twin-cone/).

A sufficient condition for $Z$ and $X\vee Y$ to be homotopy equivalent is if both $X$ and $Y$ are well-pointed. Then, the inclusion $\{x_0\}\sqcup\{y_0\}\hookrightarrow X\sqcup Y$ is a cofibration, hence its pushout $[0,1]\hookrightarrow Z$ is a cofibration. Since $[0,1]$ is contractible, the quotient map $Z\rightarrow Z/[0,1]\cong X\vee Y$ is a homotopy equivalence.